# How to increase size of this font in Chart.js?

Tags: html, css, chart.js

I need some help.I'm trying to increase font-size for this badges, and I have no idea how to do that. Maybe can you help me? I have tried before fontSize but doesn't affect the style.

**Badges:**

[image]

**Here is my code:**

```
<script>

    new Chart(document.getElementById("doughnut-chart"), {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
      labels: {!!$labels->toJson()!!},
      innerHeight: "50%",

      datasets: [
        {
          backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2","#3cba9f","#e8c3b9","#c45850"],
          data: {!!$values->toJson()!!},


        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,

        layout: {
            padding: {
                left: 35,
                right: 0,
                top: 0,
                bottom: 0
            }
        },
                legend: {
      display: true,
      position: 'right',
      labels: {
        fontColor: "#000080",
        boxWidth: 25,
        fontSize: 25,

      }
    },


    </script>
```

Comment: Check this document link for fontsize: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/fonts.html

Comment: Use `defaultFontSize` property while intializing `chart` object.

Comment: `Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize= 25';`